# Prevent android tv rows fragment/Browse fragment from saving the old positions of cards in the list row?

Tags: android, android-tv

I'm using rows fragment for displaying card items and i have 4 list rows.
When I'm traversing through the list row items vertically its ok going down but when going back up the selection is on the last selected item!
I want to prevent that and make the position 0 as the default selection when traversing up.

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You better save the last Selected Item to sharedPref or just a variable.